# What is the best MemCache solution for ASP.NET applications?

Tags: asp.net, scalability, memcached

What is the best MemCache solution for ASP.NET applications running in a windows server environment? Why?

Comment: Could you not use the asp tag for asp.net questions.  ASP is ambigious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also check out [Microsoft Velocity](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/velocity), especially if you're at a place that prefers Microsoft products.

Answer (score 0):

My sentiments exactly - [My Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/161106/distributed-cachesession-where-should-i-turn)

From what I've gathered, [memcacheddotnet](http://sourceforge.net/projects/memcacheddotnet/) is the best free options,
[scaleout](http://www.scaleoutsoftware.com/) if you want to pay